# How to center-align the numbering, vertically, in the enumerate environment?

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate

Imagine you have an enumerate environment and one of the items spans many lines. Normally, the numbering (e.g., 1., 2., 3., ...) is aligned with the top of the item, i.e., the first line. How can I have it vertically aligned in the center?

Example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that 
\item short line
\item short line
\item this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that 
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: put the text in a minipage or parbox {`\linewidth`} theyarevertically centred by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you encase the multi-line items in `parbox`es of width `\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} % allow simplified syntax for length calculations
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \parbox{\linewidth}{%
this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that}
\item short ling
\item short ling
\item \parbox{\linewidth}{%
this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that this is a ling that}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.

Comment: The vertical spacings are not uniform, though.

Comment: @egreg  - Switching from `minipage` to `\parbox` brings some relief.

Comment: @Mico I don't think so, as both use the same internals. Also, why subtracting `\leftmargin`?

Comment: @egreg - "Why subtract `\leftmargin`?" Ah, that was a left-over from the earlier version (the one that used a `minipage`). Fixed now. Oh, and I've upvoted your answer...

Answer (score 3):

The following assumes that the text in the items is equally vertically spaced (no too high or deep line) and is a single paragraph.

The idea is to count the number of lines in the paragraph and raise the `\parbox` accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}

\newsavebox{\centeritembox}
\newcommand{\centeritem}[1]{%
  \par\prevdepth\maxdimen
  \sbox{\centeritembox}{%
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
      \strut#1\strut\par
      \xdef\centeritemboxlines{\the\prevgraf}%
    }%
  }%
  \item
  \raisebox{%
    \ifodd\centeritemboxlines
      \numexpr(\centeritemboxlines-1)/2\relax\baselineskip
    \else
      \dimexpr(\ht\centeritembox+\dp\centeritembox-\baselineskip)/2\relax
    \fi
  }{\usebox{\centeritembox}}%
  \par\prevdepth\maxdimen
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[34][1-4]

\begin{enumerate}

\centeritem{\lipsum[1][1-3]}

\centeritem{\lipsum[1][1-5]}

\centeritem{Short line}

\centeritem{\lipsum[1][1-5]}

\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[35][1-4]

\begin{enumerate}

\item \lipsum[1][1-3]

\item \lipsum[1][1-5]

\item Short line

\item \lipsum[1][1-5]

\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[36][1-4]

\end{document}
```

As usual, `showframe` and `lipsum` are just for the example.

[image]